# What is the direction of に in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> この力によって神様達は下界の者達**に**持ち上げられる。

Are the 下界の者達 the ones doing the action of 持ち上げられる to the 神様達 or are the 神様達 the ones doing the action of 持ち上げられる？

I'm confused because I learned passive form as [subject] wa/ga [agent] ni [passive form verb], but the translation for this is: This power is basically what the gods gave the to the Lower World Humans.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation is an art.  It could help you learn a foreign language just as often as it could get in your way of understanding it.

> " This power is basically what the gods gave the to the Lower World Humans."

is clearly ***not*** a literal translation of the original:

> 「この力{ちから}によって神様達{かみさまたち}**は**下界{げかい}の者達{ものたち}**に**持{も}ち上{あ}げられる。」

In the original, the subject of the sentence is 「神様達」, but in the translation, it is "this power".

> Are the 下界の者達 the ones doing the action of 持ち上げ**られる** to the 神様達 or are the 神様達 the ones doing the action of 持ち上げ**られる**？

「下界の者達」 are the ones doing the action of 「持ち上げる」, not of 「持ち上げ**られる**」.  They are doing the "lifting up" the 「神様達」 with the help of 「この力」.

「神様達」 are on the receiving end of that action performed by 「下界の者達」.

「下界の者達**に**」 = 「**by** 下界の者達」

Comment: I was wondering can the word before the に not be the agent? Because I saw a sentence in the novel I'm reading and it said 壁に取り付けられた姿見。 No other interpretation seemed to make sense other than "The mirror, that was stuck to the wall." Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the に-marked argument can just be the normal indirect object of the verb, even when the verb is in its passive form.